# I cannot catch mouse signals on widgets within a wibox.container.scroll

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I am constructing widgets dynamically from from the output of `iw dev interface scan` I then add them to a scroll box held in a wibox. The problem I find is that the `mouse::enter` and `mouse::leave` signals I connect the widgets to do not catch the mouse signals when inside the `wibox.container.scroll`. All the rest of the code works as intended and the signals are caught as intended if I omit the `wibox.container.scroll` wrapper.

The widget template to be added to the scroll container:

```lua
function wifitbox.new(ssid, screen, interface)
    tbox = wibox.widget{
        {
            {
                wibox.widget.textbox(ssid[2] .. " " .. ssid[3]),
                {
                    wibox.widget.textbox(ssid[4]),
                    halign = "right",
                    widget = wibox.container.place
                },
                layout = wibox.layout.ratio.horizontal
            },
            margins = beautiful.xresources.apply_dpi(10, screen),
            widget = wibox.container.margin
        },
        id = "tbox",
        bg = beautiful.wifi_tbox_bg or "#928374",   
        shape = function(cr, width, height)
            gears.shape.rounded_rect(cr, width, height, 5)
        end,
        widget = wibox.container.background
    }

    awful.spawn.easy_async('bash -c "sudo iw dev ' .. interface .. ' station dump | awk \'FNR == 1 {print($2)}\'"', function(stdout)
        if(gears.string.split(stdout, "\n")[1] == ssid[1]) then
            tbox.bg = "#b16286"
        end
    end)

    tbox:connect_signal("mouse::enter", function()
        tbox.bg_cache = tbox.bg
        tbox.bg = "#689d6a"
    end)

    tbox:connect_signal("mouse::leave", function()
        tbox.bg = tbox.bg_cache
    end)

    return tbox
end
```

The two `:signal_connect()` statements are the ones in questions.

The widgets are added to the scroll container a follows:

```lua
    awful.spawn.with_line_callback(cmd, {
            stdout = function(line)
                local ssid = gears.string.split(line, "\t")
                wifitbox_table:get_children_by_id("tbox_list")[1]:add(wifitbox(ssid, screen, interface))
            end,
            output_done = function()
                self:set_widget(wifitbox_table)
            end
        })
```

The widget the containing the scroll container is as follows:

```
local wifitbox_table = wibox.widget{ 
        scrollbtn,
    {
        id = "scroll_box",
        speed = 100,
        extra_space = beautiful.xresources.apply_dpi(5, screen),
        layout = wibox.container.scroll.vertical,
        step_function = wibox.container.scroll.step_functions.linear_increase,
        {
            id= "tbox_list",
            spacing = beautiful.xresources.apply_dpi(5, screen),
            layout = wibox.layout.fixed.vertical()
        }
    },
    spacing = beautiful.xresources.apply_dpi(5, screen),
    layout = wibox.layout.fixed.vertical,
}
```

As I mentioned before if i remove the *"scroll_box"* widget around the *"tbox_list"* widget the signals connect without issue. But then obviously I don't get scrolling.

And finally all of it put together:

```lua
local awful = require('awful')
local wibox = require('wibox')
local gears = require('gears')
local beautiful = require('beautiful')

local wifimodal = { mt = {} }
local wifitbox = { mt = {} }
local setmetatable = setmetatable

function wifitbox.new(ssid, screen, interface)
    tbox = wibox.widget{
        {
            {
                wibox.widget.textbox(ssid[2] .. " " .. ssid[3]),
                {
                    wibox.widget.textbox(ssid[4]),
                    halign = "right",
                    widget = wibox.container.place
                },
                layout = wibox.layout.ratio.horizontal
            },
            margins = beautiful.xresources.apply_dpi(10, screen),
            widget = wibox.container.margin
        },
        id = "tbox",
        bg = beautiful.wifi_tbox_bg or "#928374",   
        shape = function(cr, width, height)
            gears.shape.rounded_rect(cr, width, height, 5)
        end,
        widget = wibox.container.background,
    }

    awful.spawn.easy_async('bash -c "sudo iw dev ' .. interface .. ' station dump | awk \'FNR == 1 {print($2)}\'"', function(stdout)
        if(gears.string.split(stdout, "\n")[1] == ssid[1]) then
            tbox.bg = "#b16286"
        end
    end)

    tbox:connect_signal("mouse::enter", function()
        tbox.bg_cache = tbox.bg
        tbox.bg = "#689d6a"
    end)

    tbox:connect_signal("mouse::leave", function()
        tbox.bg = tbox.bg_cache
    end)

    return tbox
end

function wifitbox.mt.__call(_, ...)
    return wifitbox.new(...)
end

setmetatable(wifitbox, wifitbox.mt)

function wifimodal.new(screen, interface, curSSID)

    self = wibox {
        screen = screen,
        width = screen.geometry.width / 5,
        type = 'modal',
        height = screen.workarea.height/2,
        x = screen.geometry.width - screen.geometry.width/5,
        y = beautiful.xresources.apply_dpi(beautiful.wibar_height or 25, screen),
        ontop = true,
        visible = true,
        bg = beautiful.bg_normal,
        fg = "black",
        opacity = 0.8,
        shape = function(cr, width, height)
            gears.shape.rounded_rect(cr, width, height, 5)
        end
    }

    self:connect_signal('mouse::leave', function()
        self.visible = false
        self = nil
    end)

    local scrollbtn = wibox.widget{
        {
            {
                widget = wibox.widget.imagebox,
                resize = true,
                image = gears.filesystem.get_configuration_dir() .. "widgets/wifi/arrow_up.png",
                forced_height = beautiful.xresources.apply_dpi(25, screen),
            },
            widget = wibox.container.place,
            valign = "center",
        },
        shape = function(cr, width, height)
            gears.shape.rounded_rect(cr, width, height, 5)
        end,
        widget = wibox.container.background,
        bg = beautiful.wifi_scroll_btn_bg or "#d79921",
    }

    scrollbtn:connect_signal("mouse::enter", function()
        scrollbtn:emit_signal_recursive("scroll::continue")
        scrollbtn.bg = beautiful.wifi_scroll_btn_bg_hover or "#458588"
    end)

    scrollbtn:connect_signal("mouse::leave", function()
        scrollbtn:emit_signal_recursive("scroll::pause")
        scrollbtn.bg = beautiful.wifi_scroll_btn_bg or "#d79921"
    end)

    local scan_awk = gears.filesystem.get_configuration_dir() .. "widgets/wifi/scan.awk"
    local cmd = 'bash -c "sudo iw ' .. interface .. ' scan | awk -f ' .. scan_awk .. '"'
    local wifitbox_table = wibox.widget{ 
            scrollbtn,
        {
            id = "scroll_box",
            speed = 100,
            extra_space = beautiful.xresources.apply_dpi(5, screen),
            layout = wibox.container.scroll.vertical,
            step_function = wibox.container.scroll.step_functions.linear_increase,
            {
                id= "tbox_list",
                spacing = beautiful.xresources.apply_dpi(5, screen),
                layout = wibox.layout.fixed.vertical()
            }
        },
        spacing = beautiful.xresources.apply_dpi(5, screen),
        layout = wibox.layout.fixed.vertical,
    }

    local scrollbox = wifitbox_table:get_children_by_id("scroll_box")[1]
    scrollbox:pause()

    wifitbox_table:connect_signal("scroll::continue", function()
        scrollbox:continue()
    end)

    wifitbox_table:connect_signal("scroll::pause", function()
        scrollbox:pause()
    end)

    awful.spawn.with_line_callback(cmd, {
            stdout = function(line)
                local ssid = gears.string.split(line, "\t")
                wifitbox_table:get_children_by_id("tbox_list")[1]:add(wifitbox(ssid, screen, interface))
            end,
            output_done = function()
                self:set_widget(wifitbox_table)
            end
        })


    return self
end

function wifimodal.mt.__call(_, ...)
    return wifimodal.new(...)
end

return setmetatable(wifimodal, wifimodal.mt)
```

Here is a screen shot for some context:

[image]

Also, if you don't have the answer but notice something else you can critic feel free. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem I find is that the mouse::enter and mouse::leave signals I connect the widgets to do not catch the mouse signals when inside the wibox.container.scroll

The third sentence on https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/wibox.container.scroll.html is:

> Please note that mouse events do not propagate to widgets inside of the scroll container.

So, this is "working as intended".

Also: https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/3076

Comment: Thank I missed that a scroll box is not intended to extend mouse event to its children.